# When would you use "@" Angular 1.5 Binding over "<"?

Tags: angularjs

So the Angular 1.5 documentation makes it sort of unclear as to what the different use cases are for these two...

I was able to eliminate the use of brackets if I used "<" for a string binding like this:

```
    <cookie-consent-button
        ng-if="app.bundleConfig.adchoices.displayType"
        display-type="app.bundleConfig.adchoices.displayType"
        ghostery-link="app.bundleConfig.adchoices.link[vm.currentLanguage]">
    </cookie-consent-button>
```

---

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.directives')
        .component('cookieConsentButton', {
            bindings: {
                displayType: '<',
                ghosteryLink: '<'
            },
            templateUrl: 'app/components/cookieConsentButton/cookieConsentButton.html'
        });

})();
```

instead of using the "@" binding where I had to do this:

```
    <cookie-consent-button
        ng-if="app.bundleConfig.adchoices.displayType"
        display-type="{{app.bundleConfig.adchoices.displayType}}"
        ghostery-link="{{app.bundleConfig.adchoices.link[vm.currentLanguage]}}">
    </cookie-consent-button>
```

---

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.directives')
        .component('cookieConsentButton', {
            bindings: {
                displayType: '@',
                ghosteryLink: '@'
            },
            templateUrl: 'app/components/cookieConsentButton/cookieConsentButton.html'
        });

})();
```

So to me it just seems like I can get away with a cleaner syntax by using "<" instead of "@"---. Are there any advantages to using "@" at all or is the "<" the new way to go?

Comment: The [documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.10/docs/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) quite clearly states the differences between the bind methods

Comment: But the documentation never really states when to use one or the other

Answer (score 0):

The value "@" for a property of the isolated scope of a component is described in the ["Directive Definition Object" documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object), section "scope":

> `@` or `@attr` - bind a local scope property to the value of DOM
>   attribute. **The result is always a string** since DOM attributes are
>   strings

For this reason you are able to write values without curly brackets.

At the contrary ([documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)):

> The `<` symbol denotes one-way bindings which are available since 1.5.

So, as value of the binding variable, you need to define an angular expression evaluating to a variable. For this reason you use curly brackets.

Comment: It does say that, but it never really goes into why would one prefer the use of one over the another

Comment: Well, with "@" you get always a string as value, so if you are simply interested in a string value, use "@". At the contrary, with "<" you can pass a string but also a JavaScript object that can be more complex than a string and contains more data.

Comment: But in this case it seems like you can use "<" with strings, and have less bracket syntax as well, so is "<" just the better binding to use in general? Are there any actual advantages with "@" over "<"?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Angular documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.10/docs/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-):

### @

> `@` or `@attr` - bind a local scope property to the value of DOM
>   attribute.  If no `attr` name is specified then the attribute name is assumed to be the same as the local name.

### <

> `<` or `<attr` - set up a one-way (one-directional) binding between a
>   local scope property and an expression passed via the attribute attr.

Comment: It says that, but it never really goes into why would one use the < over the @ or vice versa

Comment: @WinchenzoMagnifico `@` is **typed**, you can only pass a string. `<` can be use for objects, arrays, etc... It really depends of your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The big differences between `@` vs`<` is `@` is intended to be used for static string value binding, one example would be the binding is defined in the template rather than in the component. For example, you can have this in the component's template

```
<child-component mode="read-only"></child-component>
```

With `<` binding, and in the childComponent, you will get `mode = 'read-only` 1) you don't have to set `$scope.mode = "read-only"` in the component's controller. 2) If you are want to pass the value, you don't have to evaluate the value in the template (note: usually you would put `mode={{mode}}` in the template if you are using `<` binding. 3) You are passing the value instead of a reference. If you need to pass a reference, you should use '<' instead.

In summary, if your binding is `string` data type and the value will not be changed (ie: you don't care about the `$onChanges` for it), use `@`. Otherwise, use `<` for one way binding.